# How do you pass commands to a Cygwin console in Windows using Inno Setup

Tags: automation, cygwin, inno-setup

I've tried variations of this, but had no luck other than the ability to start a cygwin window. (wrapped on **;** for clarity)

```
Filename: "c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe";
  Parameters: "-c c:/scripts/step1.sh paramX";
  Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated;
  StatusMsg: "Running the script..."
```

(this is for an internal install, thus cywin is installed, and all paths, scripts are known)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `-c` tells bash to read instructions from the next parameter:
e.g.

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c 'for NUM in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do echo $NUM; done'
```

you just need:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe "/scripts/step1.sh paramX"
```

So your code would look like:

```
Filename: "c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe";
  Parameters: "c:/scripts/step1.sh paramX";
  Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated;
  StatusMsg: "Running the script..."
```

Maybe this will be helpful for somebody else :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to make the whole thing part of a `cmd.exe` invocation, and then I'm not sure it will do exactly what you want/need.

I'm looking at Inno-Setup 5 documentation (may be out-of-date), but I don't think you need the `shellexec` or `waituntilterminated` flags.

Try something like

```
Filename: "cmd.exe"; Parameters: "/c c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c 'c:/scripts/step1.sh paramx'"
```

Untested, caveat emptor.